# Conflict between mathdesign and memoir chapterstyle ell

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, mathdesign

I have just come across an odd interaction between mathdesign and the ell chapterstyle in memoir. I'm using TeX Live 2013 and I believe this was introduced with the update to mathdesign 2.31.

Here's the minimal code triggering the behaviour:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\chapterstyle{ell}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter title}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

This gives the following  error:

```
! Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
    \hfill 
l.5 \chapter{First chapter title}
```

This happens regardless of which font family is chosen for mathdesign (and does not occur when mathdesign is not loaded).

The problem appears to be triggered on the memoir side by the \hrulefill in \chapterheadstart. The definition of the ell chapterstyle includes the following:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
  \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
  \hrulefill
  \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
  \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
```

Replacing the \hrulefill with \hfill or \dotfill eliminates the error, and conversely, using the above redefinition instead of the full ell chapterstyle also causes the error. But using \hrulefill in a normal paragraph does not cause an error.

What could be the problem and how could it be fixed?

Comment: As David mentions this is an error in `mathdesign`, you can see it in a non-memoir document by issuing `\hrullfill` with a blank line before and after. Caused by the missing `\leavevmode` as David remarks. The `mathdesign` maintainers should hopefully allready have been noticed (I was emailed about it last week).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

well you answered this really: `\mathdesign` changes the definition of `\hrulefill` it probably shouldn't.

This restores the definition.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\xhrf\hrulefill

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\let\hrulefill\xhrf

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
  \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
  \hrulefill
  \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
  \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter title}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

---

Or a definition which adds mathdesign's intended width parameter without breaking other uses:

```
\makeatletter
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders \hrule height \rulethickness \hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: This just occurred for me when upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to  14.04.  The second, shorter fix works for me.